# C++ identifiers are undefined despite using said identifiers earlier in the function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm currently trying to make an enemy in a game. The Enemy is meant to move towards the player using the player position (x and y coordinate) and comparing it to the enemy's coordinates. however I seem to be having problems with the identifiers.

```
void DinoEnemy::Update()
{
    DinoEnemy GetPosition(int& dinox, int& dinoy); ///calling a function that should return dinox and diny

    m_AnimatedSprite.SetCurrentAnimation(E_DinoState_Hatching);
    
    GameStateManager* pGameStateManager = C_SysContext::Get<GameStateManager>();
    GameState* pCurrentGameState = pGameStateManager->GetCurrentGameState();
    GameObject* PlayerPos = pCurrentGameState->GetPlayer();
            
    if (PlayerPos)
    {
        int playerposX = 0;
        int playerposY = 0;
        PlayerPos->GetPosition(playerposX, playerposY);
    }
    
    if (dinox << playerposX) ///Here is where the error is.
    {
        dinox++;
    }


}
```

dinox and playerposX are undeclared in the final if statement

Thanks in advance ;u;

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the full error message.

Comment: `DinoEnemy GetPosition(int& dinox, int& dinoy);` declares a function, not variables.

Comment: In `if (dinox << playerposX)` - do you really intead to do a bitshift or did you mean to use `<`?

Comment: which identifiers? For us most of them arent declared, not sure which ones your compiler complains about

Answer (score 1):

There will be an issue with the scope of `playerposX`. Since it is declared inside the `if` block, it gets out of scope outside of the `if` block.

Additionally, in case `PlayerPos` cannot be translated to `true`, e.g., if it is `NULL`, `playerposX` will never be declared at all.

You may want to declare `playerposX` outside of the `if` block. Or add the second `if` block within the scope of the first.
In other words

```
if (PlayerPos)
{
    int playerposX = 0;
    int playerposY = 0;
    PlayerPos->GetPosition(playerposX, playerposY);
    
    if (dinox << playerposX)
    {
        dinox++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks for the comment, updated that part of the answer.

Comment: @churill A possible solution I see, for the scope issue, is including the second `if` block (`if (dinox << playerposX)`) within the scope of `if (PlayerPos)`.

Answer (score 1):

#### That's not how you call a function

You have

```
DinoEnemy GetPosition(int& dinox, int& dinoy);
```

But that's no function call as your comment suggests, but a *function declaration*. You meant to declare two variables, then call the function (as you did later on in your code, so why do it wrong here?):

```
int dinox;
int dinoy;

GetPosition(dinox, dinoy);
```

---

Beware: If `GetPosition` reads from `dinox` and `dinoy` you must intialize the values, but it seems like it only writes them.

#### The scope of `playerposX` is wrong

The variables `playerposX` and `playerposY` are only visible inside the `if`-block, simply declare them outside of it:

```
int playerposX = 0;
int playerposY = 0;

if (PlayerPos)
{
    PlayerPos->GetPosition(playerposX, playerposY);
}
```

---

There should probably be an `else` that handles the case when `PlayerPos == nullptr`. After all it doesn't make sense to compare the players position to something if the player doesn't have any position.

#### Little typo

```
if (dinox << playerposX)
```

Here you probably don't want a bitshift (`<<`) but rather a smaller-than-comparison (`<`).